# Pushing a QChar in QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qchar

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a (argc, argv);

    unsigned char VEL_LEFT = 0;
    VEL_LEFT  = VEL_LEFT | 100;

    QString packet;
    packet.push_back (QChar (VEL_LEFT));

    qDebug () << "VEL_LEFT: " << VEL_LEFT;
    qDebug () << "packet: " << packet;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The intention here is to manipulate 8 bits by ORing or ANDing them, and then storing them in a string.

Then I would like to read the output as decimal.

Output of this program is:

```
VAL_LEFT: 100
packet: "d"
```

What is "d" here?

Comment: 100 is the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) code of character 'd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to first manipulate 8 bits by ORing or ANDing them. Then I want to store them in a QString, and then I would like to read the output as "decimal".

Following works.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a (argc, argv);

    unsigned char SOP         = 0;
    unsigned char E_STOP      = 0;
    unsigned char DIRECTION   = 0;
    unsigned char VEL_LEFT    = 0;

    QString packet;

    packet.append (SOP);

    E_STOP    = E_STOP | 1;
    packet.append (E_STOP);

    DIRECTION = DIRECTION | 3;
    packet.append (DIRECTION);

    VEL_LEFT  = VEL_LEFT | 100;
    packet.push_back (VEL_LEFT);

    qDebug () << "VEL_LEFT: " << VEL_LEFT;

    qDebug () << "packet0: " << (int)packet[0].toLatin1();
    qDebug () << "packet1: " << (int)packet[1].toLatin1();
    qDebug () << "packet2: " << (int)packet[2].toLatin1();
    qDebug () << "packet3: " << (int)packet[3].toLatin1();

    qDebug () << "packet: " << packet.length();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

100 is the way your machine encodes a lower case d character. So

```
char x = 'd';
```

is the same as

```
char x = 100;
```

You may be confusing numbers with representations. One hundred is a number. It can be represented as the string "100" or by a hundred cars or by a sentence like "one more than ninety-nine'. It is the same *number* however represented.

"100" is a representation. In base 10 it represents the number one hundred. But in other representation systems, it can represent other numbers.

You made the string store the number one hundred. Then you printed it using your system's character representation. Well, your system uses the number on hundred to represent the character "d".

What do you want your string to store? The number one hundred? The characters "1", "0", "0"? Or what?

Comment: You did store the number 100 in the string. But then you printed out the contents of the string as a character. The number 100 is the same as the character `d` in the representation your system uses. (Just as the number ten is the same as the digit string "10" in base 10 representation.) If the string stores a number, you have to print its output as a number.

Comment: (Or do you mean you want the string to store a representation of the number 100 in base 10?)

Comment: Violet's answer does not make the string store the number 100. It makes it store the string "100". (Which can represent one hundred, or four in binary, or any number of other things.)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That would leave this particular OP with a very serious misunderstanding about the distinction between values and representations that would be devastating to his future programming efforts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for further explanation and understanding my confusion.  I will explain again. I want to first manipulate 8 bits by oring or anding them. Then I want to store them in a string. Then I would like to read the output as decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want
`packet.push_back (QString::number(VEL_LEFT));`

instead of
`packet.push_back (QChar (VEL_LEFT));`

`QString::number` takes a number and returns a string with that number's representation.
E. g. if `VEL_LEFT` equals 100, `QString::number` will return the string "100".

Answer (score 0):

what you probably wanted is this?

```
unsigned char tmpString[4];
*(uint32_t *)tmpString = 3158065;
```

"100" is (like if you type it on your keyboard) a "1" (ascii 49) followed by two "0" (ascii 48) and a 0 to determine the end of the string.